# PHP: How to upload a big file from one server to another server?

Tags: php, server, file-transfer

I have two different servers, each running PHP. Now the user uploads a file through a  (on server A), which is up to 100 MB big.

How can I now put this file on server B? The user can not upload it there by his own.

And is it possible to do this task in the background, so the user has not to wait until this task is done?

Comment: what kind of access do you have on these servers? Are files are accessible via URL on server A?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
`After file upload code`, put this code:

```
shell_exec('scp /path/to/file username:password@serverB:/path/to/destination > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

This code will copy your file from **server A** to **server B** in background, and the user will not wait.

***/path/to/file*** - is path to your uploaded file on **server A**

***username:password*** - is username and password you need to login on **server B**

***/path/to/destination*** - is the path, where you want to copy you file on **server B**

> ***> /dev/null 2>&1 &*** - Redirect both stdout and stderr to /dev/null, then background it.